# How to do json serialization using C#?

Tags: c#, json, ashx

How to do json serialization using C# ?

[image]

Comment: What is the isue?

Comment: change your tag? c -> c#

Comment: Hey instead of posting image of code you can put the particular code.

Comment: you can check how i do this in razor. it may help 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47610061/cannot-get-json-data-with-ajax-in-razor-pages/47620690#47620690

Comment: By using newtonsoft.json.dll we can easily parse JSON

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to serialize your object

```
var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(*Your object*);
```

You have to download the Newtonsoft library from [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/)